# Data from web api not binding to view in Angular

Tags: angular

I have some data coming in from a web api, but the data is not binding to the view for some reason, I have a service for the api call and then I am injecting that into the component.ts file and into the html, so far I have:

**The web api structure(rest) result in console**

```
result: Array(1)
0:
active: "true"
activity_due: ""
additional_assignee_list: ""
approval: "not requested"
approval_history: "
etc etc
```

**service.ts**

```
getIncident(s_id, cId): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.incidentApiUrl + "/" + s_id + "?customer_id=" + cId)
       .pipe(
         catchError(this.handleError)
       );
   }
```

**componet.ts:**

```
constructor(private service: nowService,
        private appComponent: AppComponent,
        private userService: UserService,
        private router: Router,
        private http: HttpClient,
        private route: ActivatedRoute
      ) {
        this.receivedUser = { firstname: '', email: '', lastname: '', name: '' }
        this.receivedIncident = { number: '', opened_at: '', description: '', short_description: ''}; this.receivedLocation = {city:null, country: null}
      }

      private getIncident() {
        this.service.getIncident(this.s_id, this.customer_id).subscribe((data) => {
          this.loading = true;
          console.log('Result - ', data);
          console.log('incident data is received');
          this.loading = true;
          this.receivedIncident = data.result;
          //this.service.getLocationsCustomer(this.receivedIncident.location.value).subscribe(location => {
            if (this.receivedIncident.location) {
              this.service.getLocations(this.receivedIncident.location.value).subscribe(location => {  
                  console.log('location --', location)

                  this.loading = false;
                  this.receivedLocation  = location.result;
              });
            } else {
              this.loading = false;
            }
        })
      }
```

**html.binding.**

```
<h2 class="text-secondary">Incident #{{receivedIncident.number}}</h2>
```

Might be something to do with the data structure in the web api?? any ideas?

Comment: I guess you are not getting object with property number from api right

Comment: Thats correct, but no errors in console

Comment: there wont be any errors in the console but it wont print anything on screen... I guess u need to get the property from api there is no problem in angular

Comment: I have got the property in the api call.... in the question I have just put the structure of the api call not all fields thats why I have etc etc

Comment: Can you post the code in stackblitz with some dummy data so that i can help you out..

Comment: It looks like from the code that `data.result` is an array?  You could access index 0, `{{ receivedIncident[0].number }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write as below as per your json result structure.

```
this.receivedIncident = data.result[0];
```

or

```
 this.receivedIncident = data[0];
```

in getIncident() function as I have seen your result in array with all the properties.